# C# read multiple Excel files

Tags: c#, excel

Is it possible to make an application that reads multiple excel files from a folder and extracts some information from them?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is.

Comment: just read one extract info, and continue until the files in the folder end

Comment: You must be kidding! Two upvotes for a question _"possible to extract some  infos from excel?"_

Comment: This article was just posted today and reminded me of  your question: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is, and here is how using Interop. The first thing you need to do is add the Excel Interop library to your project. You can do this by creating a new Visual Studio solution, right clicking on **References**, selecting **Add Reference** and then selecting **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** from the .NET tab.

Then you need to add a using statement for Excel, and one for InteropServices (as we are interoping with a COM object):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Then, inside a method, you need to create an **Application** object:

```
Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
```

Next, create a **Workbook** object for each workbook you want to read from, like so:

```
Excel.Workbook workbookOne;
Excel.Workbook workbookTwo;
Excel.Workbook workbookThree;
```

Now use the Application object to open each workbook, and load each one into its respective Workbook object:

```
workbookOne = application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\workbookOneLocation.xlsx");
workbookTwo = application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\workbookTwoLocation.xlsx");
workbookThree = application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\workbookThreeLocation.xlsx");
```

Now you need to decide what information you want to extract. Once you have done this determine which worksheet in the workbook it is on,and then figure out the number by simply looking at the tabs and counting. In the below example, **Sheet2** is number 1, **Sheet1** is number 2 and **Sheet3** is number 3:

[image: Example]

Create a variable for each piece of information you need like so (any value type variables will need to be nullable):

```
string firstPieceOfInformationINeed;
string[] secondPieceOfInformationINeed;
double? thirdPieceOfInformationINeed;
```

Let's say that the first piece of information we need is a string in Cell A1 on sheet one inside workbook one, the second piece is Cells B2 - B4 on worksheet two inside workbook two, and the third piece is a number on cell C5 on worksheet three inside workbook three. We would do this:

```
string firstPieceOfInformationINeed;
string[] secondPieceOfInformationINeed;
double? thirdPieceOfInformationINeed;

Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
Excel.Range range;

worksheet = workbookOne.Sheets[1];
range = worksheet.Cells["1", "1"];

firstPieceOfInformationINeed = range.Value as string;

worksheet = workbookTwo.Sheets[2];
range = worksheet.Range["B2", "B4"];

secondPieceOfInformationINeed = range.Value as string[];

worksheet = workbookThree.Sheets[3];
range = worksheet.Cells["3", "5"];

thirdPieceOfInformationINeed = range.Value as double?;
```

Then we close the workbook, using a boolean value to indicate whether or not we want to save changes:

```
workbookOne.Close(true);
workbookTwo.Close(false);
workbookThree.Close(true);
```

Now quit the application:

```
application.Quit();
```

And release the COM object:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
```

Now you are done with Excel, and have all of the different pieces of information you need stored as C# variables, and you can do with these what you wish.

Comment: since i dont know the number of files in a folder and their names would it be possible to obtain their names like that:string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");   and create workbooks for every path in the array ..and then do what u suggested to extract the information

Comment: @SilviaStoyanova Sure, just check to see that the files have xls or xlsx extensions and loop through them

Comment: there wont be any other files  in that folder..but yes you are right just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, and if you want to to that without Excel Interop you can use ClosedXML altough it works with excell 2007 + .

Comment: I would suggest [**epplus**](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439).

Comment: never tried it, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NPOI (http://npoi.codeplex.com/) or NetOffice (http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) library