# How to read the xls and xlsx files using c#

Tags: c#, openxml, xls

How to read the xls and xlsx files using c# **with OpenXML format Without using the OLEDB connection**. I am looking for Open XML format procedure.

Below is the code in which I used the OLEDB preocedure. But I am looking for OpenXML format.

```
public static DataTable ConvretExcelToDataTable(string FilePath)
{
    string strConn = string.Empty;

     if (FilePath.Trim().EndsWith(".xlsx"))
     {
         strConn = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", FilePath);
     }
     else if (FilePath.Trim().EndsWith(".xls"))
     {
         strConn = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";", FilePath);
     }

    OleDbConnection conn = null;
    OleDbCommand cmd = null;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = null;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Requirement is to implement the above conversion in **OpenXML format**. Thanks.

Comment: XLS is not OpenXML. So you cannot use the OpenXML SDK to read XLS files. You can use it only for XLSX files.

Comment: I answered a similar question recently [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12746187/969613)

Comment: Anyone please clarify my doubt in the above comment. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, if Excel is not present the code will not work

Comment: Does above mentioned  OLEDB procedure will work in case target machines doesn't have Office installed? Please suggest..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want the OpenXml SDK for the xlsx:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425

But for the XLS, you won't be able to use this the XLS format is not based on xml.

I use the NPOI library for accessing older files:

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

The NPOI library also supports xlsx, so this would give you a consistent way of accessing them.  Downside is you'll have to loop through sheets/rows/columns manually, and build up the dataset which will probably affect performance if you have large workbooks.  If you want to use queries to access the data, OLEDB is the only method I've found.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel installed, you could use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

Comment: In Client machine, Excel may not be installed. That's the main reason, I am looking for an alternate solution like OpenXML format. Thanks.

Comment: looking for the same solution

Comment: Thing is if you're requiring the spreadsheet to be initially saved in a format other than .xls then you're not actually wanting to read an Excel spreadsheet any more and simpler solutions become available- bog standard csv.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\` from the connection string. You can give as below.

```
conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+filepath.ToString() + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;");
```